# conditional statement base on the date

Tags: excel, vba

The vba code below needs to check if the date in column B is between 1st April 2017 and 28th April 2017 then enter in column A "April 2017". However the "Formula=" line gets a syntax error. Could you help please

```
  With Sheets("xxxx")
 With .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    .Offset(, 1).Formula = "=IF((AND(B2>=DATE(2017,4,1),B2<=DATE 
  (2017,4,28))),"Apr'17","")"
    .Offset(, 1).Value = .Offset(, 1).Value
 End With
 End With
```

Comment: The change you posted in your comment is **NOT** what was recommended by @pnuts.  But why not just do the check directly in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 1)
        .Formula = "=IF(AND(B2>DATE(2017,3,31), B2<DATE(2017,5,1)),B2,"""")"
        .NumberFormat = "mmm yy"
    End With
End With
```